What happens in $\vdash_{PA} \forall x Prov(sb_x (\ulcorner \phi \urcorner, x))$ or $\vdash_{PA} \forall x \phi(\underline{x})$ for a non-standard x?
In the book A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic the author introduces the notion of a numeral $\underline{n}$ for arithmetical theories like $PA$ on page 107 as the terms $\underline{n} = S^n(0)$ and then defines the substitution function $sb_x(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner, \dot{x}) = \left[\ulcorner \phi \urcorner\right]^{cf(\dot{x})}_\dot{x}$ on pages 232 (top) and 248-249. Here $\dot{x}$ is the Gödel number of the term $x$, $cf(n)$ is the Gödel number of the term $\underline{n}$ and $\left[\ulcorner \phi \urcorner\right]^\dot{y}_\dot{x} = \ulcorner \phi \frac{y}{x} \urcorner$ and $\ulcorner \phi \urcorner$ is the Gödel number of $\phi$. Then he introduces a special provability predicate $\square \phi \left[x\right] = Prov(sb_x(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner, x))$ on page 277 (def.), which essentially replaces the variable $x$ with the term $\underline{x} = S^x(0)$ (the introduction on p. 250 might give additional information for the following question).
Now, i am fairly certain that i understand all of this correct, so this might be very quick to answer, however i really want to make sure i get everything right.
On page 277 he argues that $\forall x \square \left[\phi(x)\right]$ is different than  $\square \forall x \phi(x) (\equiv Prov(\ulcorner \forall x \phi(x) \urcorner))$ because in the first one $\phi(\underline{n})$ is proven for all $n$ separately and in the latter one we have a single proof for all elements. However, there is a second notion in which this might differ: The first one only proves $\phi$ for standard numbers (or their isomorphic equivalent in the respective model) while the latter one could become false due to non-standard numbers.
Now the question is this: If we substitute a variable $x$ in a formula $\phi(x)$ by the term $\underline{x} = S^x(0)$, what happens, if $x$ is a non-standard number? Are we always guaranteed to only get the isomorphic equivalent of some standard number? I think this is true, because by representing $cf$ in $PA$ as a formula we essentially define a function in the natural numbers. However, the definition of "representable" (page 241) doesn't define what happens, if the argument is a non-standard number. So by that anything could happen with that predicate. Meaning, that maybe $cf(\dot{x})$ could result in substituting a term $S^x(0)$ that is a non-standard number, if $x$ is also non-standard (something like $S^{\infty + 1}(0) = \infty + 1$). The author doesn't really specify how that would be defined, but it wouldn't make sense to me, since the $\underline{n}$ are predefined terms in the language. So i guess, a representable function must always have an image in $\mathbb{N}$?
I am sorry for basing that question heavily on a book, however i tried to define everything self sufficiently and i think, all of this is standard in arithmetization and Gödelization, so i hope anyone can still answer that.
EDIT: An other way to phrase the question would be: Could $\exists x \square \left[\phi(x)\right]$ be true in some model, because $\phi(x)$ is $\textbf{only}$ true for some non-standard number $x$, even though $x$ is replaced by $\underline{x}$? I know that this can not be the case in $PA$ because of $\omega$-consistency, however maybe in an other theory that doesn't have $\mathbb{N}$ as a model?

You don't have the option to include $S^x(0)$ in a formula unless $x$ is a specific standard natural number, because that's all the syntax of first-order logic allows. Do you see? And does that help?

@RobArthan that makes sense, but how is the formula $\forall x \square \left[\phi(x)\right]$ then defined, since $PA$ has non-standard models?

@MarvinBergmann Defined within a nonstandard model you mean? In a nonstandard model, there will be a nonstandard term $S^x(0)$ for any $x$ that it can plug into (what it thinks are) formulas. (All the numbers in the model are "standard" according to the model.)

To answer the question under "edit" (though I'm not quite sure I understand your question and its relation to the edit), PA proves its own $\Sigma_1$ completeness, so this gives a bunch of stuff that, if witnessed, is provably witnessed. For instance,  a model of $\sf PA +Con(PA) + \lnot Con(PA + \lnot PA)$ won't think $\sf PA$ proves any (externally) standard number is a $\sf PA$ proof of $\sf \lnot Con(PA)$, but there will be some nonstandard number that the model thinks is such a proof, and moreover by completeness it necessarily thinks $\sf PA$ proves this.

@spaceisdarkgreen i don' think i get what you are saying. Every model of $PA$ must have an isomorphic segment to $\mathbb{N}$, because they must contain $0, S(0), S(S(0)), ...$ and these are replaced by their respective terms. However, the model might contain an element $m$ that is not some repeated successor of $0$. My question is, if we have a formula $\phi$, which is wrong for every $S^n(0)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, can $Prov(sb_x(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner, m))$ still be true in that model, or will $S^m(0)$, by which $x$ get's replaced by $sb_x$ map to some $S^n(0)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

To give an example: $sb_x(\ulcorner x = S(x) \urcorner, x)$ will be the Gödel number of the formula $S^x(0) = S(S^x(0))$ per definition and that is wrong in $\mathbb{N}$. However, maybe a model $M = \mathbb{N} \cup X$ has some $m \in X$ such that $\exists x sb_x(\ulcorner x = S(x) \urcorner, x) \equiv \exists x S^x(0) = S(S^x(0))$ becomes true for $x = m$?

@MarvinBergmann Yes, it can be true. In my example above I'm saying $\phi(x)$ would be "$x$ is a proof in $\sf PA$ of $\sf \lnot Con(PA)$". But if you don't care about also $Prov(sb_x(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner,n))$ being false for every externally standard $n$, then just a model of $\sf PA + \lnot Con(PA)$ and $\phi(x)$ being any (externally always false) formula you wish is an easier example.

@MarvinBergmann That was a response to your second to last comment. The thing in your latest comment can't happen since it's provable in PA that $x\ne S(x)$

Ah, now i get your example and yes, it makes sense now. I just got confused, because the number of the proof in $Prov$ itself doesn't get substituted, but you use the proof as a variable $x$ in $\phi$, so then it works (so we have a nested provability statement if i understand it correctly). However i am not quite convinced, since for $\exists \square \phi$ and the $\phi$ you gave as an example, this is true. But with the substitution instead, we use predefined terms. On page 250 the author only explicitly defines a sequence of those terms for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

@MarvinBergmann The definition of terms is inductive. If $t$ is a term $S(t)$ is a term an so on. Via some numeric coding, you can define terms in formalized arithmetic, satisfying these same inductive rules. So you have some arithmetic function $\sigma$ that takes a code $\tau$ for a term and $\sigma(\tau)$ is the code for the term that is the successor symbol applied to the term represented by $\tau.$ Then you can define, inductively, for any number $n,$ a function $\sigma^n$ that corresponds to applying successor $n$ times.

@MarvinBergmann But this is a formal definition, and all you did was use some of the PA axioms to guarantee these functions were all well defined. So it works just as well in nonstandard models of those same axioms. The nonstandard model will have a function $\sigma^n$ that you can apply to the (codes for) terms in that model and it doesn't care if $n$ is standard or nonstandard, though of course if it is nonstandard then "$S^n 0$" as computed by the model won't have anything to do with any real-life external term, unlike any term you might compute in $\mathbb N.$

@spaceisdarkgreen okay thank you! But then some remarks in the book don't make sense to me, do you have an explanation for those? 1) On page 277 he says, that $\vdash \phi(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is expressed by $\vdash \square \left[\phi\right]$ but in the latter we can now have more terms than just those representing standard numbers. 2) He then states, that due to $\omega$-incompl. this $\forall \square \left[\phi\right]$ may be less than $\forall \square \phi$ (i guess this is just due to not having a single proof?).

@spaceisdarkgreen 3) on page 287 he states, that $\vdash \phi \rightarrow \square \left[\phi\right]$ expresses the provable $\Sigma_1$-completeness. However, if $\square \left[\phi\right]$ can now have terms that do not represent standard numbers, than i don't understand this statement. Is it, because we still might not cover all non-standard numbers with those terms? If you want, you can put your previous comments and possible answers to my follow ups into an answer and i will accept that.

@MarvinBergmann I would say "$\vdash \phi(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$" is expressed (i.e. written formally in the language of arithmetic) by $\forall x\square[\phi].$ He says "reflected in PA", not "expressed", which I guess adds the turnstile at the beginning, indicating PA proves the formal statement. And yes, we can have more terms/proofs: the arithmetical statement $\forall x\square[\phi]$ means a different thing in a nonstandard model than it means in $\mathbb N$ (i.e. "$\vdash \phi(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$")... as does any arithmetical statement. Yes, I'll just write an answer.

I'll note that Rautenberg seems to just be working at the level of formalizing provability in arithmetic and not bringing models into it. Talking about models tends to just add confusion if model theoretic techniques aren't actually needed, in my opinion. The anchor we have is that if something makes sense as a formal development in $\sf PA$ (or another theory), then it makes sense in any model via the usual rules of interpretation. So even if we want to get nonstandard models involved, it is beneficial to first understand the formalization, rather than understanding things in terms of the standard interpretation and trying to extrapolate to nonstandard models.
So for instance, we have the informal notion that for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \varphi(S^n0)$ which we might still more informally write as $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\varphi(n).$ How can we formalize this notion in arithmetic? Well, the most tedious / difficult parts are probably familiar... coming up with a numbering system for terms, formulas, and proofs, defining the substitution predicate and the proof predicate for $\sf PA$, all that.
But now we want to be able to talk about a bunch of different proofs, indexed by a natural number $n$. Well, that's new, but not so hard compared to the foregoing. We have some number $\ulcorner 0\urcorner$ expressing the term $0$, and then we have a function $f_S$ that takes $\ulcorner t\urcorner \mapsto \ulcorner St\urcorner.$ I've written this as if there is always an actual "$t$" there, but really this is just a formally defined arithmetical function that satisfies some properties. Then we can formalize what it means to iterate $f_S$ $n$ times. This is the same as we do with any primitive recursive function... we use the formalized recursion theorem with $f_S^0(x) = x$ and $f_S^{n+1}(x) = f_S(f_S^n(x)).$
So now we know how to express "$\mathsf{PA}\vdash \varphi(n)$" formally: $$\mathsf{prov_{PA}}(\mathsf{subst}_x(\ulcorner\varphi(x)\urcorner, f_S^n(\ulcorner0\urcorner))).$$ Note, now you should not be thinking of $n$ as a natural number, but as a formal variable. In particular we can universally quantify over it, and this is what Rautenberg's notation $\forall x \square [\varphi]$ means (when we rename the free variable to $x$ rather than $n$). It's a bit cluttered since I left $x$ explicit in my notation there, but note that the unquantified formula has the same exact free variable as the original formula $\varphi$, so it makes sense to express formalized $\Sigma_1$-completeness as $\forall x (\varphi(x) \to \square[\varphi](x))$
So now, about (nonstandard) models. Again, the nice thing is that every formal development in $\sf PA$ carries over in any model of $\sf PA,$ the statements/terms just mean different things when interpreted in different models. The thing to appreciate is that we don't just have extra proofs in a nonstandard model, but extra formulas and terms as well, corresponding to our inductive definitions being iterated through nonstandard numbers. While we don't have external terms $S^n(0)$ corresponding to nonstandard numbers, amongst our formalized terms, we'll find $f^x_S(\ulcorner 0\urcorner)$ for any $x$ in the model, even nonstandard. So just like it's unproblematic to take a formula $\varphi(x)$ and plug in a $a$ from the nonstandard model and interpret the resulting sentence $\varphi(a)$ in the nonstandard model, we can do the same thing with $\square[\varphi](x)$ (which is after all just a formula). And we get something that the model thinks means "the sentence obtained by substituting the number $a$ into $\varphi(x)$ is provable in $\sf PA.$"
So no, we don't have to assume somehow that anything we substitute in "becomes standard". As far as the model's concerned, $f^x_S(\ulcorner 0\urcorner)$ is just the term representing $x$ in it's version of the language of arithmetic, just like on the outside $S^n 0$ is our term representing $n$ in the language of arithmetic.
Finally, you ask about whether $\exists x \square_{\mathsf{PA}}[\varphi](x)$ could be true in a nonstandard model and only witnessed by nonstandard elements. Hopefully it doesn't seem so mysterious now, but here's an example: Let $M\models \sf PA + Con(PA) + \lnot Con(PA + Con(PA)$ and consider the formula $\varphi(x):=\sf Proof_{PA}(x, \ulcorner \lnot Con(PA)\urcorner)$ Now, for every external number $n$, $\sf PA$ can prove that it is not a proof of $\sf\lnot Con(PA)$, since it isn't, and that fact is computable. By $\Sigma_1$-completeness and since the model thinks $\sf PA$ is consistent, we will have $M\models \sf \lnot Proof_{PA}(n, \ulcorner \lnot Con(PA)\urcorner)$ for every standard $n$ in the model. But of course, since the model thinks $\sf PA + Con(PA)$ is inconsistent, it will think there is some proof $a\in M$ of $\lnot \sf Con(PA)$ from $\sf PA$, i.e. $M\models \sf Proof_{PA}(a, \ulcorner \lnot Con(PA)\urcorner)$, and moreover, by formalized $\Sigma_1$-completeness, we have $$M\models\mathsf {\square_{PA}}[\mathsf{Proof_{PA}}(x, \ulcorner \lnot \mathsf{Con(PA)}\urcorner)](a).$$

thanks for the detailed answer! If i understand this correctly, we express $\vdash \phi(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\textbf{syntactically}$ in the model with those terms, however this does not mean, that $\textbf{semantically}$ we will always get standard numbers? So we are expressing something, but this "intended" expression must not agree with the semantic interpretation? And we $\textbf{express}$ the $\Sigma_1$-completeness in $PA$ with that formula, but this does not guarantee to mean the same externally?

but this means, that the expression for the $\Sigma_1$-completeness does not necessarily have to be true, right (the book only proves that for sentences, not for general formulas)? But then how can you apply that to prove, that $\square_{PA} \leftProof_{PA}(x, \ulcorner\lnot Con(PA)\urcorner)\right$ must be true?

@MarvinBergmann He seems to prove it in general for formulas (see thm 2.1. and the preceding paragraph). Since it's provable, it holds in all models.
